# Cucumber - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, collections, cucumber

I am trying to automate a scenario by using Maps in Cucumber DataTable using multiple test data. In this test we will pass Username and Password two times to the test step. So our test should enter Username & Password once, click on LogIn button and repeat the same steps again.

I have tried using a for loop to repeat the test using Maps collection.
1. I am getting an error saying Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type `Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,String>`
2. When i convert it into `Map<Object, Object>`, I get another error saying The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

```
    Feature File Scenario
    Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
     Given User is on Home Page
     When User Navigate to LogIn Page
     And User enters Credentials to LogIn
     | Username   | Password |
        | testuser_1 | Test@153 |
        | testuser_2 | Test@154 |
     Then Message displayed Login Successfully

Step Definition
//Maps in Data Tables with Multiple Test Data


    @Then("^user enters Credentials in LogIn$")
        public void user_enters_username_and_password(DataTable userCredentials) throws Throwable {
            //Write the code to handle Data Table
             for (Map<String, String> data : userCredentials.asMaps(String.class, String.class) ) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(data.get("username"));
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(data.get("password"));
            }
        }
```

Expected - convert from element type Map to Map
Actual - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map to Map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try assign result to intermediate variable first?

```
List<Map<String, String>> rows = userCredentials.asMaps(String.class,  String.class);
for (Map<String, String> data : rows) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shall modify your code as per below suggested implementation.

```
@Then("^user enters Credentials in LogIn$") 
public void user_enters_username_and_password(DataTable userCredentials) throws Throwable {
List<Map<String, String>> list = userCredentials.asMaps(String.class,String.class);
for (Map<String, String> data : list)
{
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(data.get("username"));
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(data.get("password"));
}
}
```